# Plugin's shortcode not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I have tried as the following

```
$my_postid = 12;//This is page id 
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
```

I have written shortcode in the page with id 12. It doesn't works. Please help!! !

Comment: You need to clarify. What are you trying to do? Is the code you provided located in your shortcode callback? What is the `str_replace` for?

Comment: The above code is written in template file. I have written shortcode in the other page with id 12. Basically I want to call shortcode written in another page in the current template file.

Comment: The shortcode of the plugin doesnot work by the above code.

Comment: The shortcode is written other page's content in the backend.

Comment: Take a look at the `get_shortcode_regex` function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex

Comment: I am not getting how to implement this function... please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`get_shortcode_regex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) function to check the post content and isolate the shortcode. Replace `my_shortcode` with the actual identifier of the shortcode you're trying to get:

```
$content_post = get_post( 12 );
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content_post->post_content );
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

preg_match( '/' . $pattern . '/s', $content, $matches );
if ( is_array( $matches ) && $matches[2] == 'my_shortcode' ) {
    $shortcode = $matches[0];
    echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
}
```